# How to remove the black border around rotated & masked image in result? OpenCv Python

Tags: python-2.7, opencv, image-processing, image-rotation, imutils

I have the task of generating data for deep learning. I take seed images, rotate them and plot them randomly on a background. The issue is the rotation results in a broken line boundary around the image and I can't figure out why it appears or how to get rid of it.

```
def rotateSeed(img):
rotated = imutils.rotate_bound(img, randint(0,360))
for row in range(rotated.shape[0]):
    for col in range(rotated.shape[1]):
        if (rotated[row,col,0] == 0) and (rotated[row,col,1] == 0) and (rotated[row,col,2] == 0):
            rotated[row,col] = default[0,0]
return rotated
```

Code explanation: default is the background color in the seed image. Rotation produces a black region I cover with the default.

Only one other person has had this problem and the solution does not explain much. It did not even rotate: [OpenCV](https://answers.opencv.org/question/193860/how-to-remove-the-black-border-around-rotated-masked-image-in-result-opencv-python/)

[Original seed image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yTtkC.png)
[Rotated seed image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1oXiA.png)

Comment: you can take a look at this.. https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2017/01/02/rotate-images-correctly-with-opencv-and-python/

Comment: The issue may have been with the data rather than the code on rotation.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code for rotation:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread('C:\\Code\\1.jpeg')
num_rows, num_cols = img.shape[:2]

rotation_matrix = cv2.getRotationMatrix2D((num_cols/2, num_rows/2), 30, 1)
img_rotation = cv2.warpAffine(img, rotation_matrix, (num_cols, num_rows))
cv2.imshow('Rotation', img_rotation)
cv2.waitKey()
```

Comment: Dear Andy_101, under the hood imutils uses these functions and the link you shared is precisely the one I followed because this approach directly cuts the seed in some rotations. It also did not solve the border issue as it is still there. :(